Arduino keypad shield with motor
I bought an Arduino keypad shield.
I want to operate a DC or servo motor when I press button on the keypad shield.

In image, I connected keypad shield with an Arduino Uno by wiring up J1, J2, RW, E, RS, D4, 5, 6, 7, 5V, GND, GND and A0.
I checked that the keypad shield is operating normally with only these 13 connected.
But is it possible to operate a DC or servo motor when I press button on the keypad shield?
If so, where should I connect the motor?

No, you can't connect a motor or servo directly to the LCD/keypad shield.
You will also need an Arduino Motor shield, for a motor, something like this:

or an Arduino Servo shield, for a servo, something like this:

As can be seen from the photo, the motor shield is stackable, allowing you to have you LCD/keypad shield on top (the screw terminals will be accesible, although you will probably have trouble using the header pins).
However, the servo shield isn't (generally) stackable, due to the servo(s) plugging into the header pins on the top. You would have to use DuPont jumper leads to connect the LCD/keypad shield at the same time.
Note: For the servo shield you have to supply additional current (see the screw terminals bottom left), and maybe the same for the motor shield. The Arduino by itself (or rather its power supply) can't really supply enough power to move a motor.

Then, you mean that Arduino Uno board can't operate the motor by receiving a button from LCD without the parts you introduced? Here, motor is connected to Arduino Uno.

"Here, motor is connected to Arduino Uno." Here? Where? Is there meant to be a link? Anyway, for the servo shield you have to supply additional current (see the screw terminals bottom left), and maybe the same for the motor shield. The Arduino by itself (or rather its power supply) can't really supply enough power to move a motor
